# How to change year options of django's selectDateWidget

Tags: django, django-widget

I want to use django's selectDateWidget for a form but the options for years are from 2012-2021. I need to display past years and probably up to 1980. How can I modify selectDateWidget?

```
lessTime = forms.DateField(required=False, widget=SelectDateWidget())
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass a `years` argument:

```
lessTime = forms.DateField(required=False, 
                           widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1980, 2012)))
```

Comment: and how to do it per class?